# EDMessage import framework

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

How can i sue EDMessage framework in my project ? Could you provide some steps.

I want to send a mail using

```
NSString *text; // assume this exists this

headerFields = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]; 
[headerFields setObject:@"Joe User <joe@example.com>" forKey:@"To"]; 
[headerFields setObject:@"Hi there" forKey:@"Subject"];

text = [text stringWithCanonicalLinebreaks];

mailAgent = [EDMailAgent mailAgentForRelayHostWithName:@"mail.example.com"]; 
[mailAgent sendMailWithHeaders:headerFields andBody:text];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am the person who pulled EDMessage out of the trashbin several years ago, and based on my experience I would be truly amazed if you can get it to work on iOS - plus its really huge. I understand many people use 'MailCore' on iOS to send mail outside of the Apple frameworks - did you look at that?